# NodeJs/Express: Authorise all endpoints except one

Tags: node.js, express

In my NodeJs/express based application, I am authorizing calls to all the endpoints by using the following middleware.

```
 app.use(restrictByCookieMiddleware);
```

I want to authorize all endpoints except one i.e. I don't want "restrictByCookieMiddleware" middleware to run for "/metrics" endpoint. Is there a way to escape one endpoint?

[Here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples), I found some examples that matches endpoint for which middleware should run, I am looking for a solution that skips one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have a couple of choices:

First, you can just define the one exception route handler BEFORE the middleware.  Then, it will handle that route and the routing will never get to the middleware.

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    // handle that one special route here
});

// all other routes will get this middleware
app.use(restrictByCookieMiddleware);
```

Second, you can make a wrapper for the middleware that compares to the one specific route and skips the middleware if it's that route:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // shortcircuit the /login path so it doesn't call the middleware
    if (req.path === "/login") {
       next();
    } else {
       restrictByCookieMiddleware(req, res, next);
    }
});

// then, somewhere else in your code would be the /login route
app.get("/login", ...);
```

Third, if you have multiple routes that you want to skip the middleware for, you can segment things by router.  Create a router for the non-middleware routes and put all of them on that router.  Hook that router into the `app` object first.

Then, create a second router that contains the middleware and has all your other routes on it.

Answer (score 1):

Place that specific route, you want to exclude, before this line:

```
app.use(restrictByCookieMiddleware);
```

So this will solve your problem.